# How to verify call-signature hash value in GraphQL?

Tags: httprequest, zoho, gql

I need to implement GraphQL access for a third party (Zoho subscription) that has a certain webhook implementation I can not change.
The call-authentication mechanism consists of arranging parts of a request (query string and body) into a certain string, calculate a hash value using a certain algorithm, and verifying that against the value provided in a call header.
When implementing it in GQL

- I know how to access header values.
- I don't know how to access request properties like URL query string or body in a string form. Web search didn't come up with anything useful.

Anyone know whether accessing the request object properties in GQL is possible? Any links?

Comment: In the meantime I found this: https://blog.apollographql.com/a-guide-to-authentication-in-graphql-e002a4039d1

Comment: When constructing the ApolloServer object, you have access to the request object, and yo can save its properties (like url or body) in the context variable.